# How to use activity instead of fragment in default navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am using default navigation drawer on android studio ... I want to make case 0 in onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) method switch to activity instead of fragment with navigation drawer still exist on the left side of screen

what I have now newActivity can start normaly but I can't use navigation drawer any more

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment objFragment = null;

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, NewActivity.class));
                break;
                }
       }
```

please I need help

Answer (score 1):

If you still need the navigation drawer in your activity, then it makes no sense that you start a new activity, but use a fragment instead. 
Maybe you could provide more info regarding why you specifically want an activity to receive a more accurate answer.

Comment: Cuse Iam using gcm service and in this activity there is receiver and some jar's method calls that doesn't work in fragment

Comment: As far as I know you can indeed use gcm services in fragments (not sure about those jar's methods you mention though). If you don't want to struggle making your stuff work with fragments, I would just create a child activity, which automatically places a nice back button in the action bar

Answer (score 0):

There are two alternatives to be implemented for this case.

1. Use Navigation Drawer also in the `NewActivity`.
   This is not a better approach, but fulfil your requirement that you need to use drawer in the `NewActivity` and you don't want to use fragment.
2. Convert `NewActivity` to fragment and replace it with the new fragment in `case 0`using `FragmentManager`/`SupportFragmentManager`.
   This is better approach.

Comment: could I use the same navigation drawer in the second activity?